# how correctly unpipe nodejs stream

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, duplex

I try to figure out why `.unpipe` call is no-op if the stream has been piped after `.pause`:

```
b.on('data', console.log.bind(console, "on b -> "));
c.on('data', console.log.bind(console, "on c -> "));

a.pause();

a.pipe(b);
a.pipe(c);

a.resume();

a.unpipe(b);
a.unpipe(c);
a.write("foo");
```

prints:

```
//on b ->  foo
//on c ->  foo
```

It seems to be because of `.pause()` call. But it's important to keep the stream paused 'till all streams are piped. **How can I workaround this issue in an elegant way?**

There is *opportunity* to attach 'data' event listener on source stream as destination stream's write function.

```
b.on('data', console.log.bind(console, "on b -> "));
c.on('data', console.log.bind(console, "on c -> "));

writeToB = b.write.bind(b);
writeToC = c.write.bind(c);


a.pause();

a.on('data', writeToB);
a.on('data', writeToC);

a.resume();

a.removeListener('data',writeToB);
a.removeListener('data',writeToC);

a.write("foo");
```

but this approach feels like bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try hooking up the data events after you pipe.

Hooking the data event causes the pipe to start flowing.

```
a.pipe(b);
a.pipe(c);

b.on('data', console.log.bind(console, "on b -> "));
c.on('data', console.log.bind(console, "on c -> "));

a.unpipe(b);
a.unpipe(c);
a.write("foo");
```